# Should I add the Poster or the article published in the proceedings to my CV?

Tags: conference, cv, poster, proceedings

I presented a poster 3 years ago in a small conference and added the poster to my CV and ResearchGate profile. At the request of the conference organisers, I also wrote a short article describing the poster that was published in the conference proceedings one year ago.

I guess it would be unethical to add both the poster and the article to my CV and ResearchGate profile, but which one should I use? Is it better to use the article in the proceedings? And in that case, should I consider it as a poster, an article or a conference paper?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CV isn't governed by any legal rules. You can include what you like. But you should label things correctly to avoid criticism.

In this case I see no reason, and no ethical concern, not to include both if you label one as an article and the other as a poster, perhaps with the same title. Partly this is because you were invited to write the article. Therefore they really are two different things unless you just wrote the same thing in the article as in the poster, which seems unlikely.

But, it probably isn't a "conference paper" if it didn't go through the normal review process in its final form.

And, if you only want to include one, then I'd think the article is the more important one.